# Drawing bitmaps and ovals on a canvas

Tags: java, android, eclipse, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to create an user View in this way:

Bitmap A as background ("hal9000rim")

Oval B over the background (designed on the canvas)

Bitmap C over the Oval ("reflBitmap")

Here's the code of the View Class:

```
public class HalView extends View {

    final Bitmap reflBitmap;
    final Paint corePaint;
    RectF coreRectf, reflRectf;

    public HalView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        reflBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hal9000refl);
        coreRectf=new RectF(0.2f,0.2f,0.8f,0.8f);

        corePaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        corePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        corePaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);

        //corePaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(0.5f, 0.5f, coreRectf.width() / 2, new int[]{Color.rgb(50, 132, 206), Color.rgb(36, 89, 162),
        //    Color.rgb(27, 59, 131)}, new float[]{0.5f, 0.96f, 0.99f}, TileMode.MIRROR));

        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hal9000rim);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        reflRectf=new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight());
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.View#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //canvas.drawOval(coreRectf, corePaint);
        canvas.drawOval(new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 400.0f), corePaint);
        //canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, 100f, 100f, corePaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(reflBitmap, null,reflRectf, null);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {

        final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        final int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
        final int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

        final int side=Math.min(chosenWidth,chosenHeight);

        setMeasuredDimension(side,side);

    }

    private int chooseDimension(final int mode, final int size) {
        switch (mode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            return size;
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        default:
            return getDefaultDimension();
        }
    }

    private int getDefaultDimension() {
        return 50;
    }}
```

I have 2 problems:
the first is that I get an error when the layout is inflated, here's the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.HalView
        android:id="@+id/halView1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/halView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="240dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the error:

03-04 23:54:52.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26490): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo/org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo.HalActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.HalView

The second problem is that when I'm trying to use the RadialGradient in place of the simple CYAN colour I get in Eclipse layout preview this error:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

But colours and position arrays in the gradient seems to be well formed to me.
And of course I'm not able to launch the app on the device.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Any help for my question?

Comment: Nobody there can give me an hint about this problem? Thanks

Comment: What are the sizes of the bitmaps? It sounds like you want to take a bitmap in background, put a oval over it that is transparent, then do a bitmap inside of that oval. Is this true?